# why did [8,9] still in lst after I had run this code

Tags: python, list

here is my code:

```
lst=[[6,7],[8,9],[10,11], [12, 14], [13, 18]]
lst.sort()
lst1=[]
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    if lst[i][-1]<lst[i+1][0]:
        lst1.append(lst[i])
print(f'lst1 = {lst1}')
for i in lst:
    if i in lst1:
        lst.remove(i)
print(lst,'and',lst1)
```

and here is the result:

```
lst1 = [[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
[[8, 9], [12, 14], [13, 18]] and [[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

I don't know why [6,7] and [10,11] were removed but [8,9] still there, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the copy of the list instead of the list:

```
for i in lst[:]:
    if i in lst1:
        lst.remove(i)
```

Let's see the problem:

```
[[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 14], [13, 18]]
```

When you iterate over the list, you remove the first element.
So the list is now:

```
[[8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 14], [13, 18]]
```

`[8,9]` has shifted to the first position, but iterations only go forward. So now `[10,11]` is removed.

So the left part:

```
[[8, 9], [12, 14], [13, 18]]
```